# Nano. Copy (Alt+6) Doesn't work

Tags: nano

I am using nano version 2.2.6 and I have no idea why copying isn't working.

What I do now is cut and then paste it two times, but before, I was using `Alt + 6` without problem, what happens¿? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After marking your desired text, copy it by entering (alt+shift+6) or (alt+^).

Comment: Not working here: Not assigned: M-&

Answer (score 0):

In my graphical desktop environment (i3 window manager), which "hosts" applications such as nano, nano's copy keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> didn't work because I had previously set up i3 to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> as its own modifier key. With this configuration, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> is interpreted and swallowed by i3 ("select i3 workspace/desktop 6") and never reaches nano.

The workaround of adding <kbd>Shift</kbd>  to "escape" i3's keyboard interpretation also didn't work, as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> was also explicitly bound by i3 ("move current window/application to i3 workspace/desktop 6").

I solved this issue by changing i3's modifier key to <kbd>Windows</kbd>.

Since then, nano's copy keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> works again and doesn't collide with i3's <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Here it was Console, that has keyboard shortcuts to switch the Tab.

Alt-6 will switch to Tab 6, if it exists.

I have changed that shortcut in the settings of konsole to something else, after it, nano works like documented.